# Shrinking/Splitting decimal number

Tags: c#, split, decimal

I have been playing with `DateTime` in C#, and have come up with some useful code for calculating days between dates.

I use the following code to work out how many days there are between the dates, then I divide the number of days by 7 to work out how many weeks.

```
DateTime SDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31);
DateTime EDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 18);
double resDays = SDate.Subtract(EDate.Date).TotalDays;
double Weeks = resDays / 7;
string resWeeks = Weeks.ToString();
```

However, the result of `Weeks.ToString()` returns a lengthy decimal number
-19.5714285714286
I have removed the - with `resWeeks = resWeeks.Replace("-","");`
I used this code to separate the lengthy number into two parts

```
string s = Weeks.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] parts = s.Split('.');
int i1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int i2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);
labelWeeks.Text = i1.ToString() + i2.ToString();
```

However, `i2.ToString()` still returns 57, I would of course like this to only be 5. How could I do this?

I would like `"-19.5714285714286"` to become `"19 5"`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `resWeeks` returns `-19.7142857142857`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrAyjH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `0.0` as format string instead of `0.00`.

As format strings for real numbers go, the number zeroes in front of the dot describe left padding, and the number of zeroes after dot describe the number of decimal places you want. If you want one decimal place, just say so.

Comment: @Hellooo123, if you liked the answer, could you please "accept" it by clicking the big transparent "checkmark" icon right under the number of votes on the left?

Answer (score 2):

**First Point:** I think you must try `EDate.Subtract(SDate.Date)` not `SDate.Subtract(EDate.Date)` so the result is a positive value and there is not need for `.Replace("-","")`

```
  DateTime SDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31);
  DateTime EDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 18);

  double resDays = EDate.Subtract(SDate.Date).TotalDays;
  double Weeks = resDays / 7;
```

**Second Point:** The result is not an integer because 138 days is between 19-20 weeks. You may round the result like this:

```
string resWeeks = Math.Round(Weeks).ToString(); //resWeeks = 20
```

Or if you are looking for 19 5

```
string resWeeks = Weeks.ToString("0.0").Replace('.',' ');
```

Comment: He wants `19 5`, not `20`.